# After type in EditText, how to make keyboard disappear

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

From the android tutorial :

```
pass_text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            // Perform action on key press
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

when click at EditText, it has a keyboard appear on the frame. I want to know after Enter.
How to make keyboard out from frame except click Back.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try the following

For Activity:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(curEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

In case of Fragment :

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: to hide keyboard on fragment upload i used following code and after typing in Edittext  i added the above code in btnSearch.setOnClickListener: the code is as follow:
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 16):

give the `EditText` box you have the attribute `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`
this will change the Enter button to a Done button that will close the keyboard.

Comment: A word of warning however: this doesn't seem to work on 100% of phones out there

Comment: @atraudes I have seen issues, some phones also want singleline=true haven't had an issue outside of that.

Comment: Didn't work on a Samsung Galaxy 5. I need multi-line, so will need to try something else.

Comment: Not working with or without singleline=true on nexus4 lollipop.

Comment: Have not checked documentation but using only android:singleLine="true" appears to give "Done" instead of return on the keyboard on Galaxy S6 (6.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

A working approach to get rid of the soft keyboard is to disable and then enable the TextEdit field in the Return-key event, button-press event or whatever. For example:

```
....
pass_text.setEnabled(false);
pass_text.setEnabled(true);
....
```

Comment: This answer might not fit the questioner's problem the best, but it helps all other SO's out there more. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: A work around that best served my needs when i wanted to remove focus from my edittext along with the soft keyboard that awkwardly remained on the screen .

Answer (score 0):

I think we can simply add this attribute to our EditText:

android:inputType="text"

This will automatically force the text to be on a single line and therefore when we click Enter, the keyboard disappears.